# Is it possible to run code on all pageloads on Chrome Mobile on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm looking to add some very basic functionality to all pages that are opened on Chrome on Android.

Just something very basic like if an url contains X, insert this HTML.

Is there any way this is possible? I'm coming from iOS and hoping that since Android is more open there's a way to add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: The Chrome Extension API on Desktop lets you do this, but there is no Chrome Extensions API on Chrome for Android so it is not possible.